# Improve time of count function

Tags: kotlin

I am new to Kotlin (and Java). In order to pick up on the language I am trying to solve some problems from a website.

The problem is quite easy and straightfoward, the function has to count how many times the biggest value is included in an IntArray. My function also works for smaller arrays but seems to exceed the allowed time limit for larger ones (error: Your code did not execute within the time limits).

```
fun problem(inputArray: Array<Int>): Int {
    // Write your code here
    val n: Int = inputArray.count{it == inputArray.max()}
    return n
}
```

So as I am trying to improve I am not looking for a faster solution, but for some hints on topics I could look at in order to find a faster solution myself.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an unordered array you to touch every element to calcuate `inputArray.max()`. So `inputArray.count()` goes over all elements and calls `max()` that goes over all elements.

So runtime goes up n^2 for n elements.

Store `inputArray.max()` in an extra variable, and you have a linear runtime.

```
val max = inputArray.max()
val n: Int = inputArray.count{ it == max }
```

Comment: It is actually strange that the compiler wasn't able to optimize it.

Comment: The code gets compiled by the website, so I think the missing optimization is part of the problem solving challenge